# different Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID for same device on Different machine apk

Tags: android

I am getting AndroidId using code `String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

if i run this code on different machine then I am getting different android_id  for same device. Why is it so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

See the [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#privacy-all) and [documentation of ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID).

For apps installed on a device running Android 8.0, the value of ANDROID_ID is now scoped per app-signing key, as well as per user. The value of ANDROID_ID is unique for each combination of the app-signing key, user, and device. As a result, apps with different signing keys running on the same device no longer see the same Android ID (even for the same user).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recomment to read this post https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

It is not good practice to get unique device Id.

If you still want to do it try

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

also dont forget that it might be null

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about debug builds, It may be because you have different debug (Default) keystore.